# Latest/Recent posts widget title link

Tags: widgets

I have been struggling with this for a few hours now...

I want to add a link to my recent posts widget title.

I have tried a number of options given in forums but nothing seems to work.

Tried adding link tags around and in between `echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;` but must be going wrong somewhere.

Please can you have a look at the widget code and let me know if adding a link to widget title is possible?

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget Name: Recent Posts with Excerpts Widget
 * Description: A widget that allows to display a recent posts with excerpts and date and author info (optional).
 * Version: 0.1
 *
 */

/**
 * Add function to widgets_init that'll load our widget.
 * @since 0.1
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'latest_posts_load_widgets' );

/**
 * Register our widget.
 * 'Latest_Posts_Widget' is the widget class used below.
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
function latest_posts_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Latest_Posts_Widget' );
}

/**
 * Custom Category Widget class.
 * This class handles everything that needs to be handled with the widget:
 * the settings, form, display, and update.  Nice!
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
class Latest_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function Latest_Posts_Widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget-latest-posts', 'description' => esc_html__('The most recent posts with teaser text', 'purevision') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 150, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'latest-posts-widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'latest-posts-widget', esc_html__('Digi - Recent Posts', 'purevision'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}

/**
 * How to display the widget on the screen.
 */
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $category_id = $instance['category_id'];
    $num_posts = absint( $instance['num_posts'] );
    $post_offset =  absint( $instance['post_offset'] );

    /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
    echo $before_widget;

    /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */

    if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    /* Display the Latest Posts accordinly... */
    echo '<div id="widget-latest-posts">';
    $cats_to_include = ( $category_id ) ? "cat={$category_id}&": '';
    $num_posts_query = new WP_Query( "{$cats_to_include}showposts={$num_posts}&offset={$post_offset}" );
    if( $num_posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <div class="latest_posts">
        <ul>
                    <?php while( $num_posts_query->have_posts()) : $num_posts_query->the_post(); update_post_caches($posts); ?>
    <?php
    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $postimage = vt_resize($thumb, '', 58, 58, true );
    ?>
            <li>
            <div class="pop-wrap">

            <h3><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            </div>
            </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- end widget_recent_posts -->
    <?php endif;
    echo '</div><!-- end widget-latest-posts -->';

    /* After widget (defined by themes). */
    echo $after_widget;
}

/**
 * Update the widget settings.
 */
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['num_posts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['num_posts'] );
    $instance['post_offset'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['post_offset'] );
    /* No need to strip tags for dropdowns and checkboxes. */
    $instance['category_id'] = $new_instance['category_id'];

    return $instance;
}

/**
 * Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel.
 * Make use of the get_field_id() and get_field_name() function
 * when creating your form elements. This handles the confusing stuff.
 */
function form( $instance ) {

    /* Set up some default widget settings. */
    $defaults = array( 'title' => esc_html__('Latest Posts', 'purevision'), 'category_id' => '', 'num_posts' => 3, 'post_offset' => 0);
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

    <!-- Widget Title: Text Input -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Title:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>

    <!-- Show Categories -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category_id' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Pick a specific category:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all=All&hierarchical=1&orderby=name&selected='.$instance['category_id'].'&name='.$this->get_field_name( 'category_id' ).'&class=widefat'); ?>
    </p>

    <!-- Number of Posts -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num_posts' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Number of posts to show:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num_posts' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num_posts' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['num_posts']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="2" />
        <br />
        <small><?php esc_html_e('(at most 15)', 'purevision'); ?></small>
    </p>

    <!-- Post Offset -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_offset' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Number of posts to skip:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_offset' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_offset' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['post_offset']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="2" />
        <br />
        <small><?php esc_html_e('(offset from latest)', 'purevision'); ?></small>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your widget code to include a new field called "Title Link". This, along with some additional markup, will create a link around your widget title. You'll probably need to add better validation to the Title Link field.

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget Name: Recent Posts with Excerpts Widget
 * Description: A widget that allows to display a recent posts with excerpts and date and author info (optional).
 * Version: 0.1
 *
 */

/**
 * Add function to widgets_init that'll load our widget.
 * @since 0.1
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'latest_posts_load_widgets' );

/**
 * Register our widget.
 * 'Latest_Posts_Widget' is the widget class used below.
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
function latest_posts_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Latest_Posts_Widget' );
}

/**
 * Custom Category Widget class.
 * This class handles everything that needs to be handled with the widget:
 * the settings, form, display, and update.  Nice!
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
class Latest_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Widget setup.
     */
    function Latest_Posts_Widget() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget-latest-posts', 'description' => esc_html__('The most recent posts with teaser text', 'purevision') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 150, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'latest-posts-widget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'latest-posts-widget', esc_html__('Digi - Recent Posts', 'purevision'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}

/**
 * How to display the widget on the screen.
 */
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );

    /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $titlelink = $instance['titlelink'];
    $category_id = $instance['category_id'];
    $num_posts = absint( $instance['num_posts'] );
    $post_offset =  absint( $instance['post_offset'] );

    /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
    echo $before_widget;

    /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */

    if ( $title ) {
          echo $before_title;
          if ( $titlelink ) { 
                echo '<a href="' . $titlelink . '">';
          }
          echo $title;
          if ( $titlelink ) {
                echo '</a>';
          }
          echo $after_title;
    }

    /* Display the Latest Posts accordinly... */
    echo '<div id="widget-latest-posts">';
    $cats_to_include = ( $category_id ) ? "cat={$category_id}&": '';
    $num_posts_query = new WP_Query( "{$cats_to_include}showposts={$num_posts}&offset={$post_offset}" );
    if( $num_posts_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <div class="latest_posts">
        <ul>
                    <?php while( $num_posts_query->have_posts()) : $num_posts_query->the_post(); update_post_caches($posts); ?>
    <?php
    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $postimage = vt_resize($thumb, '', 58, 58, true );
    ?>
            <li>
            <div class="pop-wrap">

            <h3><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            </div>
            </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- end widget_recent_posts -->
    <?php endif;
    echo '</div><!-- end widget-latest-posts -->';

    /* After widget (defined by themes). */
    echo $after_widget;
}

/**
 * Update the widget settings.
 */
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
    $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
    $instance['titlelink'] = $new_instance['titlelink'];
    $instance['num_posts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['num_posts'] );
    $instance['post_offset'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['post_offset'] );
    /* No need to strip tags for dropdowns and checkboxes. */
    $instance['category_id'] = $new_instance['category_id'];

    return $instance;
}

/**
 * Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel.
 * Make use of the get_field_id() and get_field_name() function
 * when creating your form elements. This handles the confusing stuff.
 */
function form( $instance ) {

    /* Set up some default widget settings. */
    $defaults = array( 'title' => esc_html__('Latest Posts', 'purevision'), 'category_id' => '', 'num_posts' => 3, 'post_offset' => 0);
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

    <!-- Widget Title: Text Input -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Title:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>

     <!-- Widget Title Link: Text Input -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'titlelink ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Title Link:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'titlelink' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'titlelink' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['titlelink']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>

    <!-- Show Categories -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category_id' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Pick a specific category:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all=All&hierarchical=1&orderby=name&selected='.$instance['category_id'].'&name='.$this->get_field_name( 'category_id' ).'&class=widefat'); ?>
    </p>

    <!-- Number of Posts -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num_posts' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Number of posts to show:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num_posts' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num_posts' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['num_posts']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="2" />
        <br />
        <small><?php esc_html_e('(at most 15)', 'purevision'); ?></small>
    </p>

    <!-- Post Offset -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_offset' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Number of posts to skip:', 'purevision'); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_offset' ); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_offset' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['post_offset']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="2" />
        <br />
        <small><?php esc_html_e('(offset from latest)', 'purevision'); ?></small>
    </p>
```

You'll have to add additional styling since you're using a link in your header tags now:

```
  .widget h3 a {
        // Same colour and style as h3 //
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, huge progress, but how do I now make it look the same as all other widgets in the footer, title heading style and spacing I mean. It looks like the H3 style is not applied to the title.

Comment: You'll probably need to add additional styling now that it is a link, I've updated my answer with a CSS example

Comment: It worked wonders. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Would you be able to mark my answer as correct? Much appreciated!